# Компановка в WPF из кода C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Имею контейнер Canvas. Необходимо в него вложить WrapPanel, который в свою очередь должен содержать textBox и Button. Необходимо из кода C# вложить их друг в друга и прописать свойства Canvas.Top Сanvas.Left для WrapPanel. Перелопатил уже пол интеренета, и так не нашел как это сделать из кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я сам разобрался

```
public void CreateNewField(int counter)
    {
        WrapPanel mainWrap = new WrapPanel();
        TextBox fieldTxtBox = new TextBox();
        Button createFieldButton = new Button();

        Canvas.SetTop(mainWrap, topStep);
        Canvas.SetLeft(mainWrap, leftPoint);

        fieldTxtBox.Name = "txb_" + counter.ToString();
        fieldTxtBox.Margin = new Thickness(3, 2, 30, 2);
        fieldTxtBox.Width = 450;

        createFieldButton.Name = "btnCreateField";
        createFieldButton.Content = "Creat Field";
        createFieldButton.Margin = new Thickness(3, 2, 0, 2);

        IAddChild containerWrap = mainWrap;
        containerWrap.AddChild(fieldTxtBox);
        containerWrap.AddChild(createFieldButton);

        IAddChild containerCanvas = mainCanvas;
        containerCanvas.AddChild(mainWrap);

        counterField++;
        topStep += 35;

        createFieldButton.Click += CreateFieldButton_Click;

    }
```